# How to write trys for a password and block after 3 trys

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am new to coding and trying to code a login but I'm having difficulty setting a limit of trys to login. I'm completely lost. This is my coding, in the second ***if*** I'm trying to set the limit ( in this case 3). Any idea how you could do that with it decreasing and stop prompting the user?

```
function TheLogin() {

  var password = "password";
  var trys = 3 // tried to make it an array but don't know if it helps

    if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
        top.location.href="correct.html";
}

    if {
        window.alert("Incorrect password, please try again. /n You have " + trys + " trys left");
    }

    else {
        window.alert("you have passed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is a school assignment since a real login doesn't work like this. But to answer your question, all you have to do is decrease the number of trys everytime the user enters the wrong password. When the number reaches 0 then open an alert saying that the user is blocked. It's just an if statement.

Comment: Try to store the trys anywhere (session, database...)

Comment: @JonasW. Can you explain what you mean by "spoiling"?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if {}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a homework assignment, since this is definitely not a secure way to handle passwords -- so I'm going to describe strategies instead of giving you complete code.

Try to think through this stuff logically before you start writing code.  If you plan things out ahead of time, you'll often find the code basically writes itself.

There are three possible conditions here: the user is out of tries, the password matches, or it doesn't match.

So your  login function is going to look something like this:

- If the user is out of tries (`trys` is zero), do nothing.
- otherwise, if the password matches, you want to alert success and redirect the user.
- Otherwise the password must not match, so you want to show the message that there are only `trys` tries remaining, and then you want to reduce that number by one for next time.

There's one other thing to deal with: your function sets `trys` to 3 every time the user makes an attempt, which would mean they'll never run out of attempts.  You need to initialize that variable somewhere other than this function.